# MySQL Dump to Directory

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to make a copy of a site to run locally, and i'm having some difficulty in downloading a dump of the mySQL database using PhpMyAdmin. (In that it doesn't work). I was wondering (and I suspect) if there is an sql command I can execute that would dump out the database to a location that I can download it via FTP.

I've found the following:

```
 mysqldump --opt --user=root --password password > /home/backup/db.sql
```

but the page says that this will only run via shell, and I don't have shel access to the server. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Command prompt from MySQL bin folder (Make sure you have Read/Write Access)
2. Use the below mysqldump command

***mysqldump -h [hostname] -u [username] -p [your database] > [your destination path][your filename.extn]***

Ex: **mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p test_DB > D:\MySQL\Dumps\test_file.sql**

***WARNING : In case, if your custom path has any spaces in between, the above query will throw an error.
[Invalid Path Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqQSJ.png)

To avoid Invalid Path Description, Give your path in double-quotes.

Ex : **mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p test_DB > D:\MySQL\"Dumps from ABC"\test_file.sql**

Answer (score 4):

```
mysqldump -u root -p -T/path/ database
```

Comment: mysqldump -u [username] -p -T/path/to/directory [database]

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Three steps Export mysql DB**

```
**step1 :** run windows command prompt

**step2 :** make where yours wamp mysql stored directory ex E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin

**step 3 :**
E:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin> mysqldump -u UserName -p PassWord dbname >c:\dbname.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

PERFORM MySQL DATABASE DUMP:

1. [Having registered mysql.exe in the Paths of Environment Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html) (On
   Windows Os)
2. [Open windows console](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/947-command-prompt.html)
3. Type the following Query:

   mysqldump [Your database Name] -u root -p > C:/[Your Destination Directory ]/[ new Backup Database Name.sql ]
4. You will be prompted for a database user password
5. Enter Password:*******
6. when the dump is over...the directory will go back to the current
   user session in Windows console

*For this to work well, replace all parameters in square braces "[ ]" with your own values without the square braces*

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is [Sypex Dumper 2](http://sypex.net/en/). It exports (backups) your database directly to disk, so you can download the backup via ftp. It is written on php, supports large databases and has a very nice interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the directory where you want store the file, then execute de mysqldump command.

```
~/Desktop$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqldump -u root  -p publicaciones > publicaciones.sql
```

PD. Use sudo to grant full permissions.
PD. If you have your PATH setup, don`t need use the full route to your MySql commands.

Comment: The OP said that they don't have shell access to the server. I don't suppose they can execute this command. Please read the question carefully.